# How to place php code in body tag using Jade?

Tags: php, wordpress, html, pug

how can I write this in Jade?

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

I tried like this

```
body(!{"<?php body_class(); ?>"})
```

but does not work.

The solutions offered in [Is it possible to write PHP in jade/pug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023440/is-it-possible-to-write-php-in-jade-pug) do not work in this specific case.

Is there any way of doing this?

I use codekit for compiling offline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to write PHP in jade/pug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42023440/is-it-possible-to-write-php-in-jade-pug)

Comment: add :    =body_class()

Comment: can you explain this more accurate? add `=body_class()` where?

Comment: shouldn't it be `<body class=<?= body_class(); ?>">` ?

Comment: No due to [wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) it is `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jade, you should escape the entire string like this
**header.jade**

```
doctype
| <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>

head
  meta(charset!='<?php bloginfo("charset") ?>')
  meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width')
  link(rel='profile' href='http://gmpg.org/xfn/11')
  link(rel='stylesheet' href!="<?= get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/style.css?v=#{version}" type='text/css')
  link(rel="pingback" href!="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>")
  - wp_head()

| <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

**footer.jade**

```
script(src!="<?= get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/core.js?v=#{version}")

- wp_footer()

| </body></html>
```

Comment: Arrrr ... I tried this before and it didn't work because of an indention error. I didn't check the error message right and thought this way it doesn't work.

So now this worked for me, thanks a lot!